# Android studio, reading data from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: android, azure, raspberry-pi, iot

I am using the java android_sample taken from azure-iot-hub
[android sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/95f8f4e80b3ec8b6fbbbc8e577e70d00c01e7a64/device/samples/android-sample)

Basically i have a Raspberry pi that sends data with a python script to the Azure iot hub.

[image: Picture off device explorer(PI data)]

As you can see from the picture, the IoT hub is receiving the data.

In Android studio, as said, I am using the android_sample code.
I added a button and textview etc... To show the data.

Now, when I go to the "Messages to Device" tab and send data everything works. My phone is receiving that data, and displaying it.

The problem is that I want the data from the "data" tab. When I start the Pi script, and then the android app, it's not receiving the data that the pi is sending.

When I "send" something from the device explorer, it is receiving that data.

if you need some code I will post it, but i'm basically using the example code, just modified a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your android app can receive data sent from device explorer because these are Cloud-to-Device data. While it can't receive data sent from the Raspberry Pi because these are Device-to-Cloud data. It is expected.

More information you can reference [Understand Azure IoT Hub messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging).

For your use case you can reference [Device to Device Communication with Azure IoT Hub](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/08/device-to-device-communication-with-azure-iot-hub/#w6V6V365jQpb0wwg.97).